# How can I fill a div with color without using background-color?

Tags: javascript, html, css, kendo-ui

I have a web application in which I am trying to print certain information.  I am using Telerik KendoUI for the grid and other controls.

What I'm doing now is I pop up a Kendo window with the print contents, make it modal, then make the modal background opaque white, so it covers everything else.  The idea is that then when the user prints, it will only see the window contents.

The problem is that, by default, the browsers do not print backgrounds.  This means that, when it prints, you still see all the other contents under the window, and even the window itself is transparent since its own background is not included.

If the user goes to the Print settings of the browser, and checks "Print backgrounds" then it works fine.  However, we cannot expect our users to do this, and we need to make it work "out of the box."

I tried several solutions from StackOverflow for printing, most of which involved popping up a new window, replacing its innerHTML contents, then printing it.  The problem I kept running into with those was that my CSS would not apply for those, even after manually putting in the HTML to include the CSS.  I could see the CSS files being requested properly and received with no error, but they still just would not apply to the window contents.

```
        $scope.printDiv = function (contentDiv) {
            var printWinWrapper = $("#caseDetailPrint");
            printWinWrapper[0].innerHTML = contentDiv.innerHTML;
            var printWin = printWinWrapper.kendoWindow({
                title: "Print",
                modal: true,
                scrollable: false,
                minWidth: "1000",
                position: {
                    top: 0,
                    left: 0
                },
                close: function(e) {
                    $(".k-overlay").css('background-color', 'black');
                    $(".k-overlay").css('opacity', 0.5);
                }
            }).data("kendoWindow");
            printWin.open();
            printWinWrapper.parent().addClass("print-window-titlebar");
            $(".k-overlay").css('background-color', 'white');
            $(".k-overlay").css('opacity', 1);
            window.print();
        };
```

So I was thinking that if I could just set the color of the ".k-overlay" (which is Kendo's way of hiding stuff behind the modal) using some method besides "background-color" CSS, that should force it to hide the rest of the page contents while that window is up.

Any ideas?

Edit: I tried box-shadow (thanks h.sh), and it is actually ignored whether I have "Print backgrounds and images" selected or not.  So it looks like I need to amend my request to include only solutions that will allow it to be printable with "Print backgrounds and images" turned off, which is the default for the browser we are targeting (IE11, and no, we can't change it).

Comment: Giant inset `box-shadow`? Not sure how that will print though.

Comment: Would a canvas element help?
(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Basic_usage)

Comment: Use @media print and set css style to only show what can be printed.

Comment: depending on your structure, it could be `@media print {
 body * {display:none;}
.popup, .popup * {display:initial;}
  
}` initial is not supported by IE11 but `:not()` should be .  *feed back on comments is also appreciated*

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of change color without using background-color, you can customize it.

I've used inner shadow

```
box-shadow: inset -1px -1px 100px   100px black;
```

```css
.bg{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  color:#eee;
  box-shadow: inset -1px -1px 100px   100px black;

}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
test
</div>
```

Comment: I just tried that, and the box-shadow also does not print, or show up in the print preview.  Unfortunately, it is not visible whether "Print backgrounds and images" is checked or not.

Answer (score 0):

if you can use background image try it:

```css
.bg{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  color:#eee;
  background:url('data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAUEBAAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=');
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">test</div>
```

Comment: Just tried it, and it does not print by default, I suppose because it is part of the "background" which is not printed in this case.